# Break a while loop with the sleep function inside after a certain period of time

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, while-loop

How can i stop a while loop after a certain time in which the sleep function is used. The condition inside a while loop does not work correctly because the sleep function pauses the execution of the code.

In this case i have delay for 40 seconds before a while loop stops:

```py
# timeout for 10 minutes
timeout = time.time() + 60*10

while True:
    if time.time() >= timeout:
        break
    # do something
    sleep(20)
    # do something
    sleep(20)
```

Comment: You are right sleep method is blocking. But what should be the expected behaviour? On what frequency do_somehting must be called? Each 20 or 40 seconds? Better describe in your question (not in comment), also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Probably, the fastest solution will be to set the certain amount of sleep.

```
timeout = time.time() + 60*10

while time.time() < timeout:

    # do something
    # added clipping negative numbers too
    time_left = max(0,min(20, timeout - time.time()))
    sleep(time_left)

    if time_left == 0:
        break

    time_left = max(0,min(20, timeout - time.time()))
    # do something
    sleep(time_left)
```

Not the most elegant solution. But should work

Answer (score 0):

you may use the code below.

```
import datetime
import time

timeout = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=20) # define here!

while True:
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    if now >= timeout:
        print('time is up !')
        break
    else:
        print('do something')
        time.sleep(5) # define here!
        continue
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem, it's a rewriting of the original code in a different way (with shorter sleep time).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need a variable sleep duration.

Something like this:

```
from time import time, sleep

timeout = time() + 10 * 60

while time() < timeout:
    # do some work
    sleep_duration = min(20, timeout - time())
    sleep(sleep_duration)
```

This means that the sleep will be **at most** 20s